# Is there any list of blog engines, written in Django?

Tags: python, django

Is there any list of blog engines, written in Django?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

EDIT: Original link went dead so here's an updated link with extracts of the list sorted with the most recently updated source at the top.

[Eleven Django blog engines you should know](http://blog.montylounge.com/2010/02/10/eleven-django-blog-engines-you-should-know/)

by Monty Lounge Industries

> - [Biblion](http://github.com/eldarion/biblion)
> - [Django-article](http://bitbucket.org/codekoala/django-articles/)
> - [Flother](http://github.com/flother/flother)
> - [Basic-Blog](http://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps)
> - [Hello-Newman](http://github.com/gregnewman/hello-newman)
> - [Banjo](http://getbanjo.com/download/)
> - [djangotechblog](http://code.google.com/p/djangotechblog/)
> - [Django-YABA](http://github.com/f4nt/django-yaba/)
> - [Shifting Bits](http://github.com/paltman/shiftingbits/) (this is now just a [biblion](http://github.com/eldarion/biblion) blog)
> - [Mighty Lemon](http://github.com/mightylemon/mightylemon)
> - [Coltrane](http://code.google.com/p/coltrane-blog/)

Comment: The site is down. One of the cons of posting a link instead of quoting the important content.

Comment: Biblion won't get install using pip due to package not found

Answer (score 4):

James Bennett has an [interesting take](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/29/django-blog) on this question:

> “where can I find a good Django-powered blogging application” is probably at the top of the frequently-asked questions list both on django-users and in the IRC; part of this is simply that, right now, there is no “definitive” Django blogging application; there are a bunch of them available if you go looking, but you’re not likely to get anyone to recommend one of them as “the” Django blogging app (unless the person doing the recommending happens to be the author of one of them).

The [blog entry](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/29/django-blog) also has a list.

Comment: Building your own blog in django is kind of a rite-of-passage. However, if you just want to get one up and running...I suggest Nathan's Basic Apps (see my answer for a link.)

Answer (score 3):

**Byteflow** is a blog engine, written on Python, using Django

Answer (score 3):

Django's powerful admin interface and easy ORM makes it a 30 minute job to build a blog that propably fits your needs; Why look for a 3rd party product when you can make it yourself very quickly?

Comment: Because blog requires comments, pingbacks, openid, atom/rss feeds, publishing api, etc.

Comment: A blog doesn't _require_ anything more than posts, actually. :)

Answer (score 3):

The book [Practical Django Projects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219386) provides a tutorial on how to create a Django blogging app.

Answer (score 1):

Nathan Borror has a great package of 'basic apps' that has a blog. These are well written, well documented apps that you should try out, get ideas from, etc.

http://code.google.com/p/django-basic-apps/

Answer (score 1):

You should check `django-blogango`. http://agiliq.com/blog is run using this blogging engine.

https://github.com/agiliq/django-blogango